# Searching for the solution to make selenium scrape products

Tags: java, html, selenium, maven, scrape

I'm working on my pet project. As for now, I want to parse product name and its' price.
Visit [shoppingSite](https://shop.silpo.ua/), press button under the map, then press it once again on the right side. Choose upper delivery option and you will be redirected to the shop. Near the search section the menu bar located. Click and choose any category. When you"ll reach the page with products, you can open developers' tool.
So, I don't know how to make selenium give me names and prices.
What I have tried:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    javascriptExecutor.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 200)");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.category.page__content")));
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.category.page__content"));
System.out.println(element.getText());
```

Selenium tells me that

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException:
Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element
```

Scrolled, waited for the elements' visibility. Did not help me.
Will be grateful for any tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the products names you can do this:

```
webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a.product-title")));
Thread.sleep(300);
List<WebElement> productNames= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.product-title"));
List<WebElement> productPrices= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.current-price"));
```

If you want to get these names and prices as a List of Strings you can use this method:

```
 public List<String> getElementsListTexts(By element){
    List<String> texts = new ArrayList<>();
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(element);
    for (WebElement el : list ){
        texts.add(el.getText());
    }
    return texts;
}
```

So it will be

```
webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a.product-title")));
Thread.sleep(300);
List<String> names = getElementsListTexts(By.cssSelector("a.product-title"));
List<String> prices = getElementsListTexts(By.cssSelector("div.current-price"));
```

Comment: You saved me, may i ask you about resources where I can learn more about selenium scraping? Thank you!

Comment: Any good tutorial about locating elements with selenium with CSS selectors and XPaths. Like this https://screenster.io/selenium-locators-best-practices/ or this https://www.apress.com/it/blog/all-blog-posts/best-practices-for-choosing-locators-for-selenium/16169400. Just ask google: selenium locators best practices or similar

Comment: Just noticed that it is YOU. Haha, are you selenium guru? Thanks once again :)

Comment: Well, not a guru, but having 6-7 years experience with it :)

Comment: wish here was "add to the friend list" button :) Have a nice day/morning/evening (;

Comment: Evening . Just don't forget to accept and upvote helpful answers 